# Format specifier for printk loff_t types?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, printk

I am working on a Linux character device driver for a school assignment and am not sure how to print the `*ppos` passed into my read function which is of type `loff_t`.

I know I must use `printk` rather than the standard library `printf` from within the kernel but I can't seem to figure out the proper format specifier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

loff_t is just a typedef. To determine which format specifier to use, you should look for its definition:

- [typedef __kernel_loff_t loff_t](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6.7/include/linux/types.h#L54)
- [typedef long long __kernel_loff_t](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6.7/include/asm-generic/posix_types.h#L87)

Then you can refer to the [Kernel's documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt) to see how to format a "long long" (%lld).